# How to use Identity Matrix to rearrange an equation

Tags: matrices, vectors, laplace-transform

I am trying to rearrange the following equation. I do not know where to bring the identity matrix 'I' into the equation. The last line is the answer I should have, but the line above it is the answer I got from working out.

[image: working out]

Am I right in thinking that 'I' somehow gets brought in at line 3, where I factor out X(s)?

Thanks

Comment: If $s$ is a number then you multiply it by the identity matrix (essentially 1) to do operations with matrices. For example If $A$ is a matrix and $s\in\Bbb R$ then $s-A$ doesn't make sense but $sI-A$, does.

Comment: Ok so I would have to bring the identity matrix in on line 4 during the factorization process to make (s - A) make sense. I assume that the identity matrix in this case would have to be the same dimensions as A. EDIT: the identity doesn't have to be the same dimensions as A but it needs to be a square matrix of nxn is A is a nxm matrix

Comment: Yes and yes. If A is not a square matrix then the identity matrix should have the same number of columns as A has rows.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: In regards to what @GNUSupporter, here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) for review.

Answer (score 1):

"Number minus matrix" makes no sense. You had $sX-AX$. To factor the $X$ to the right, you need to have a product of matrices in the first term. So 
$$
sX-AX=sIX-AX=(sI-A)X. 
$$